Azure Test Plans - Automatically transfer automated tests from visual studio to test plans
I have a suite of automated tests in visual studio which I would like to add to azure test plans.
I'm currently doing this by creating the test case manually within test plans.
Given there may be hundreds of tests that require adding to test plans,  does anyone know of an automated way in which we can add all the desired tests directly from visual studio into Azure test plans?

You can try to call the Azure DevOps REST API "Work Items - Update" in a script to associate tests with Test Case work items.

HTTP URI:

PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=7.0


Request body:

[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestName",
    "value": "{namespace.testClassName.testMethodName}"  // e.g., TestMathCalc.TestOperators.TestAddition
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestStorage",
    "value": "{assembly name}"  // e.g., TestMathCalc.dll
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestType",
    "value": "Unit Test"
  }
]


UPDATE:
If you need to create test case and then associate the test cases with the test methods in you test code, you can use a script to do the following things:

Use the API "Work Items - Create" to create new Test Case type work item and associate with the test methods in test code.

Then use the API "Suite Test Case - Add" to add the test cases to the specified test suite under specified test plan.


Below is a sample of PowerShell script as reference.
$organization = "organizationName"
$project = "projectName"

$pat = "Personal Access Token"
$base64Token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
$headers = @{Authorization = "Basic $base64Token"}

# Create a new Test Case type work item and associte it with test method in test code.
$uri_create_testCase = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/wit/workitems/`$Test%20Case?api-version=7.0"

$body_create_testCase = @(
  @{
    op = 'add'
    path = '/fields/System.Title'
    value = 'TestAddition'
  }
  @{
    op = 'add'
    path = '/fields/System.AreaPath'
    value = 'BrightRan\\Test'
  }
  @{
    op = 'add'
    path = '/fields/System.IterationPath'
    value = 'BrightRan\\Sprint-Y2024\\Sprint-M06'
  }
  @{
    op = 'add'
    path = '/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestName'
    value = 'TestMathCalc.TestOperators.TestAddition'
  }
  @{
    op = 'add'
    path = '/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestStorage'
    value = 'TestMathCalc.dll'
  }
  @{
    op = 'add'
    path = '/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestType'
    value = 'Unit Test'
  }
) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

$response_create_testCase = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri_create_testCase -Headers $headers -Body $body_create_testCase -ContentType "application/json-patch+json"
$testCaseId = $response_create_testCase.id

# Add test case to a suite with specified configurations.
$planId = 64
$suiteId = 66

$uri_add_testCase_to_testSuite = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/${planId}/Suites/${suiteId}/TestCase?api-version=7.0"

$body_add_testCase_to_testSuite = @(
    @{
        pointAssignments = @(
            @{configurationId = 28}
            @{configurationId = 29}
        )
        workItem = @{id = $testCaseId}
    }
) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 -AsArray

Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri_add_testCase_to_testSuite -Headers $headers -Body $body_add_testCase_to_testSuite -ContentType "application/json"



UPDATE_2:
To set a list all the test cases you want to create, you can try like as below:

Use a CSV file to store all the required information of the test cases.


In the PowerShell script, you can use the cmdlet "Import-Csv" to read the CSV file and get the values.


$TestCases = Import-Csv -Path .\TestCases.csv
foreach ($testcase in $TestCases)
{
    # Get required information of test case needs to craate. The In information will used in the subsequent API calls.
    $Title = $testcase.Title
    $AreaPath = $testcase.AreaPath
    $IterationPath = $testcase.IterationPath
    $AutomatedTestName = $testcase.AutomatedTestName
    $AutomatedTestStorage = $testcase.AutomatedTestStorage
    $PlanId = $testcase.PlanId
    $SuiteId = $testcase.SuiteId

    # Call API to create a new Test Case type work item and associte it with test method in test code.
    xxxxx

    # Call API to Add test case to a suite with specified configurations.
    xxxxx
}



Thanks for the reply. So from what I understand this create the association between the test code in visual studio and the test case in test plans. What im trying to do initially is copy the tests from visual studio into test plans so that I don't have to do it manually. after that i think I could use the update call to update the test assocaitions.

@bobe_b, If I do not misunderstand, you want to create new test cases to the test suite and also associate the new test cases with the test methods in you test code? If so, you can try the method shared under UPDATE in my above answer.

Yes that is correct. Ok I will try to use this method. One question with regards to using the method. How do we send in the method listed above? should we use a client like postman or similar? The MS documentation doesn't provide much detail around how to make these request, only the detail they should contain. Having not done anything  like this before I'm not sure where to start in order to get this working.

@bobe_b, You can try to use a CSV file to store the list of test cases you want to create. For more details, see UPDATE_2 in my answer.

@bobe_b, Have you tried as my suggestion mentioned under UPDATE_2 in my above answer? Is it working for you?
